# laravel: launch android activity after clicking on email verification link

Tags: android, laravel, redirect, frontend, backend

I have an Android application which has a laravel 9 backend. On the app, when the user clicks the email verification button, an email will be sent to his email containing the verification link.

```
$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
```

The problem is, when the user clicks on the verification link in his email, he is redirected to the website but I want to open the login page activity on the Android app instead.

```
$user->markEmailAsVerified();
return "Your email successfully verified.";
```

**So, is it possible to launch an activity as the user clicks on the verification link?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to read about the term ["deep linking"](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Comment: can we change laravel's default email verification link to an android deep link?

Comment: you can describe the intent-filter under the existing url without changing it in laravel. in the case of the email verification, that would be more correct. Because the user might want to validate the email from a computer or any other device where your app may not be installed